# How do Meta field names correspond to model attributes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I am writing a Django Model and different Forms to modify the model's data.

For simplification let's say my model is as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    # (...) some other properties 
    __identity_card_front = models.FileField(blank=True)

class IdentityCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('__identity_card_front',)
```

My question is: must the fields names correspond to the attributes of Profile class (the exact name of the variables definition)? Do these strings determine the HTML form field name that will be searched in form validation? And if so, how can I customise it? I don't want to have to obligatorily call my field name '__identity_card_front', but instead maybe something like 'id_front', 'idf', etc.

I have seen `labels` might be used, but I was not clear how Django treats fields tags. I could not find either a good explanation on the Docs without getting lost around low-level class definitions and properties.

Note: I am using django-2.0

Comment: have you tried to override field with form fields and widget?

Comment: @Gahan I have looked into widgets, but the issue is that I do not really understand how form fields work in reference to the model and the HTML form. If you could explain that would be great

Comment: see some code of abstraction of django they have really done very hard-work to set everything so dynamic. if you are using pycharm then you can directly go to that code. but for minimal consider that it's methods written in django which sets the form, admin model etc. documentation says to write the meta because the meta option is used to customize some of that feature/methd. like verbose name of field, model plural name, helptext etc.

Comment: Rather than worrying about having to call your form field "__identity_card_front", you should think about why you have called your model field such a terrible name, and change that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman excuse me, can you say why you say that? I would accept the criticism about it being  “terrible” if you gave a constructive explanation, I do not mind admitting mistakes or things that I ignore, I intend to learn, but you are not making it easy.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are not even answering my question. Call the field whatever. How does the field name in the model relate to the field name in the form class and in the HTML form sent by POST? Could you answer that? I do not think it might be complicated for an individual with considerable experience in Django.